# (Swift 3)generic parameter T could not be inferred

Tags: generics, swift3

I am trying to create a function which takes in nested arrays of objects like [1,[2,[3,4],[5,6]]] and return values in single array like this [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I wanted to do it for generic objects so I created a method

```
func getNestedArray<T>(array:[Any])->[T]?{

    var nestedArray:[T] = []
    for object in array{

        if object is [Any]{
        let neededArray = getNestedArray(array: object as! [Any])
        nestedArray.append(contentsOf: neededArray)
        }
        else if object is T{
            nestedArray.append(object as! T)
        }
        else{
         print("send proper array dumbass")
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nestedArray
}
```

so if the object is of type T I just append it or if it is of type array I am calling that function again and recursively should give me the correct result but I am getting the error at while calling this function. what am i doing wrong? I am just passing 'Any' type object as '[Any]'. Why does it throw this error?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Did i ask something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not telling the compiler anything about what type `neededArray` should be. It is only natural that the compiler complains. Judging from the context, I think you want `neededArray` to be an array of `T`. So explicitly say the type:

```
let neededArray: [T] = getNestedArray(array: object as! [Any])
```

Obviously this does not work because you have not unwrapped the optional. Well, if `getNestedArray` returns nil that means the array is invalid in the first place, we should probably return nil as well:

```
guard let neededArray: [T] = getNestedArray(array: object as! [Any]) else { return nil }
```

Remember to specify the type when you use the method as well!

```
let result: [Int] = getNestedArray(array: [1, [2, [3, [4]]]])!
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It worked. Sorry I am trying Generics for the first time and I could not understand that error